# How to construct sql query for the following case?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables,

**indexInfo**:

```
[indexId] [name] [type]
  101      nameA  Cars
  102      nameB  Trucks
  103      nameC  Cars
```

**userGroupXindexInfo**

```
[usergroupnumber] [indexId]

  201               101
  201               103
  202               102
  202               103
  203               103
```

There could be multiple `userGroups` assigned to the same index, how do i get a list of unique indices which belong to a list of user groups with a specific type?

So i want a list of unique indices that are assigned to user groups `(201, 202, 203)` from `indexInfo` where `type = Cars`?

In this case, it would be: 101, 103

I tried using a left outer join but was not sure if there are better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a `in` predicate to limit the `indexId` to those matching the specified groups:

```
select indexId 
from indexInfo 
where type = 'Cars' 
and indexId in (
    select indexId 
    from userGroupXindexInfo 
    where usergroupnumber in (201,202,203)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` for that:

```
SELECT t.IndexId
FROM indexInfo t
WHERE t.Type='Cars'
  AND EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM userGroupXindexInfo i 
      WHERE t.IndexId = i.IndexId
  )
```

The first condition `t.Type='Cars'` verifies the type. The second condition `EXISTS  (...)` verifies that the index is assigned to a group.

You could do the same with `GROUP BY` and a join:

```
SELECT t.IndexId
FROM indexInfo t
JOIN userGroupXindexInfo i ON t.IndexId = i.IndexId
WHERE t.Type='Cars'
GROUP BY t.IndexId
```

Comment: I will try EXISTS...i never even knew this was there in SQL...THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

use "in" to construct filtering

```
--- Select indexInfo 
Select * from Indice 
--- Filter result 
where Type = 'Cars' and indexID in 
---Liset In depends of Selected query
       ( select indexID from userGroupXindexInfo where usergroupnumber in (200,202,203))
```